# How to setup PdfSharp Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, pdfsharp

I am receiving a error in my apiPdfsharpController. The report i am printing is pulling data from the Job class. The job class is pulling data from the Customer Class. The Customer Class Data is what is causing the exception. I did add a ViewModel for the Job, however I do not know if that needs to be used here. if so I do not know how to use it instead of the Job Class itself.

> Exception Message :
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> StackTrace:
>      at TexasExterior.Controllers.PdfController.Get(Nullable`1 id) in c:\Development\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\Controllers\PdfController.cs:line 92

apiPdfController:

```
 public string Get(int? id) // allow nullable parameter
    {
        if (!id.HasValue) // if null return an empty string
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // your code :

        apiJobController adapter = new apiJobController();
        Job job = new Job();
        job = adapter.GetJob(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        try
        {

            // Create a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

            // Create an empty page
            PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
            page.Size = PageSize.Letter;
            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            XPen pen = new XPen(XColors.Black, Math.PI);
            //XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

            // Create a font
            XFont HeadingFont = new XFont("Times New Roman", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XFont BodyFont = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12);
            // Draw the text


            gfx.DrawString("Date : ", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(127, 120, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.JobContractDate.ToString(), BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(160, 120, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString("Job Number : ", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(90, 140, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.JobNumber.ToString(), BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
             new XRect(160, 140, page.Width, page.Height),
             XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString("Job Name", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(100, 160, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.JobName, BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
             new XRect(160, 160, page.Width, page.Height),
             XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString("Customer : ", BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(102, 180, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.Customer.CustomerName, BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(160, 180, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.Customer.CustomerAddress, BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(160, 195, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);

            gfx.DrawString(job.Customer.CustomerCity + job.Customer.CustomerState + job.Customer.CustomerZipcode.ToString(), BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(160, 210, page.Width, page.Height),
              XStringFormats.TopLeft);




   var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("f").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
            var filename = string.Format("{0}--{1}.pdf", job.JobName, dt);
            string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/JobSetupPdfs/"),    Path.GetFileName(filename));
            document.Save(path);

            // ...and start a viewer.
            Process.Start(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
        return string.Empty;
```

JobViewModel

```
public class JobViewModel
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public int JobOriginalContract { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobContractDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobBillingDate { get; set; }
    public int JobTotalCO { get; set; }
    public int JobRevisedContract { get; set; }
    public int JobOriginalBudget { get; set; }
    public string JobBillingForm { get; set; }
    public string JobTESPM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESSuperintendent { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public string JobMoreShit { get; set; }
    public bool JobTaxExempt { get; set; }
    public bool JobCertPayroll { get; set; }
    public int JobCost { get; set; }
    public int JobRemainingBudget { get; set; }
    public int JobProfit { get; set; }
    public int JobPercentage { get; set; }
    public int JobTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public int JobBalanceToBill { get; set; }
    public int JobPaidToDate { get; set; }
    public int JobBalanceDue { get; set; }
    public string JobAddress { get; set; }
    public string JobCity { get; set; }
    public string JobState { get; set; }
    public int JobZipcode { get; set; }
    public string JobCounty { get; set; }
    public Int64 JobPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64 JobFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public bool JobIsHidden { get; set; }

    public int JobRetainage { get; set; }
    public int JobMinWage { get; set; }
    public string JobInsProgram { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    //public int? GeoAreaId { get; set; }

    //public int? JobClassId { get; set; }

    //public int? JobTypeId { get; set; }

}
```

apiJobController

```
 // GET api/<controller>/5
    public Job GetJob(int? id)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Job model = new Job();
            model = context.Jobs.Where(j => j.JobId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return model;
        }

    }
```

JobClass

```
  public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public int JobOriginalContract { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobContractDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobBillingDate { get; set; }
    public int JobTotalCO { get; set; }
    public int JobRevisedContract { get; set; }
    public int JobOriginalBudget { get; set; }
    public string JobBillingForm { get; set; }
    public string JobTESPM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESSuperintendent { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public string JobMoreShit { get; set; }
    public bool JobTaxExempt { get; set; }
    public bool JobCertPayroll { get; set; }
    public int JobCost { get; set; }
    public int JobRemainingBudget { get; set; }
    public int JobProfit { get; set; }
    public int JobPercentage { get; set; }
    public int JobTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public int JobBalanceToBill { get; set; }
    public int JobPaidToDate { get; set; }
    public int JobBalanceDue { get; set; }
    public string JobAddress { get; set; }
    public string JobCity { get; set; }
    public string JobState { get; set; }
    public int JobZipcode { get; set; }
    public string JobCounty { get; set; }
    public Int64 JobPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64 JobFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public bool JobIsHidden { get; set; }

    public int JobRetainage { get; set; }
    public int JobMinWage { get; set; }
    public string JobInsProgram { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    //public int? GeoAreaId { get; set; }
    //public virtual GeoArea GeoArea { get; set; }

    //public int? JobClassId { get; set; }
    //public virtual JobClass JobClass { get; set; }

    //public int? JobTypeId { get; set; }
    //public virtual JobType JobType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }

}
```

Update
Angular Controller

```
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {

   var id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

View

```
                                    <label>Number:</label>
                                    <input ng-model="currentItem.JobNumber" type="text" name="JobNumber">
                                    <input ng-hide="true" ng-model="currentItem.JobContractDate" type="text" />
                                    <label>Customer:</label>
                                    <input stype="text" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerName"
                                           typeahead="customer.CustomerName for customer in customerArray | filter:$viewValue"
                                           placeholder="Enter Customer" typeahead-on-select="selectEditCustomer($item)">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label>Status:</label>
                                    <select ng-model="currentItem.JobStatus">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                                        <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                        <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
                                        <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label>Address:</label>
                                    <input disabled style="width:200px" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerAddress" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label">Name:</label>
                                    <inputng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">
                                    <label>City:</label>
                                    <input disabled style="width: 93px" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerCity" type="text">

                                    <label>St:</label>
                                    <input disabled style="width: 30px" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerState" type="text">

                                    <label>Zip:</label>
                                    <input disabled style="width: 44px" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerZipcode" type="text">
                                </div>
<inputng-click="EmailPdf(currentItem)" type="button" value="Email" />
```

Comment: It says the error is on line 92, which is line 92?

Comment: gfx.DrawString(job.Customer.CustomerName, BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,

Comment: I'm betting `job.Customer` is null then.

Comment: yes, using a break point i just saw it is null, however the CustomerId is there?

Comment: ok, think i just saw my own error. when i am passing the values from the view to the controller I am not attaching the ng-model-currentItem.Customer. i am only passing currentItem to the controller. How can I send both to the controller?

Comment: I dont think that is my problem though. any ideas?

Comment: how do I work around it?

Comment: Fix the `GetJob` function to include the customer object too

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? thanks

Comment: Try this: `model = context.Jobs.Include("Customer").Where(j => j.JobId == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Job` object has a null `Customer` property. Change the `GetJob` function to retrieve it like this:

```
model = context
            .Jobs
            .Include("Customer") //This is the important addition
            .Where(j => j.JobId == id)
            .First();
```